# NSData to NSString with åöä

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, nsstring, nsdata, non-ascii-characters

I'm downloading a webpage using NSMutableURLRequest but having problem putting that very webpage into a NSString.

```
NSString *username = @"my_username";

NSString *password = @"my_password";

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.mypage.com/login.php?username=%@&password=%@", username, password]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *returnPage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*s", [returnData length], [returnData bytes]];
```

This works fine except for special chars like åäö etc. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use the following:

```
NSString *returnPage = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

That uses UTF8 instead of ASCII.

Comment: Hmm, Xcode (4.2) tells me "ARC forbids explicit message of 'autorelease'", should I just leave to autorelease out and cross my fingers? :) I'm not so used to ARC, ObjC nor Xcode...

Comment: Tried NSString *returnPage = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; didn't work. returnPage is <nil> after execution =/

Comment: That means you are using the wrong encoding... what encoding is returned from your api?

Comment: Well, the api is not mine it is just a plain webpage. How do I see which encoding it is using?